# java:use mock parameters in generic method,it makes error

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I used TestNG and Mock in test.It occured a confused problem,and I had searched for a long time on net.I need your help...Dear

I want to do test for this method

```
@Override
public boolean addAreaToDB(String areaName, Integer areaCode) {
   if (isAreaExists(areaCode)) {
     return false;
   }
   Area area = new Area(areaCode, areaName);
   areaDao.save(area);
   onlineDiskService.initFoldersAndPrime(areaCode);
   return true;
}
```

I tried the following ways :

```
  @InjectMocks
  private AreaServiceImpl areaService;
  @Mock
  private IAreaDAO areaDao;
  @Mock
  private OnlineDiskService onlineDiskService;

  @BeforeTest
  public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddAreaToDB() {
    String areaName="";
    Integer areaCode=0;

    //first:
    Area area = new Area();
    when(areaDao.getByAreaCode(anyInt())).thenReturn(area);
    areaService.addAreaToDB(areaName, areaCode);

    //second:
    when(areaDao.getByAreaCode(anyInt())).thenReturn(area);
    areaService.addAreaToDB(anyString(), areaCode);

    //third:
    when(areaDao.getByAreaCode(anyInt())).thenReturn(area);
    areaService.addAreaToDB(areaName, anyInt());

    //forth:
    when(areaDao.getByAreaCode(anyInt())).thenReturn(area);
    areaService.addAreaToDB(anyString(), anyInt());
  }
```

The first three is ok,but the last reported an error.

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
    Invalid use of argument matchers!
    1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
    -> at 
 com.tal.peiyoupad.service.impl.AreaServiceImplTest.testAddAreaToDB(AreaServiceImplTest.java:69)
   -> at 
 com.tal.peiyoupad.service.impl.AreaServiceImplTest.testAddAreaToDB(AreaServiceImplTest.java:69)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

    For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

I searched the net.Answers are all about when(method(Mock)),there is no answer about my problem.Help me,please~

Comment: Is there anyone?Help me please....This problem has confused me for a long time ~

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix matchers and normal variables in those Mockito calls. In other words, use `Matchers.eq( areaName )` instead of `areaName`. As soon as you use one matcher, you cannot use normal values anymore. Either all params are matchers are none

Totally ok:

```
when(something( myVariable1, myVariable2, "string", 4)).then(...);
when(something( any(), any(), eq("string"), eq(4)).then(...);
```

Not ok:

```
when(something( any(), any(), "string", 4).then(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I want to use mock in generic method _addAreaToDB_.  
Totally ok:  
_areaService.addAreaToDB(areaName, areaCode);_  
_areaService.addAreaToDB(anyString(), areaCode);_  
_areaService.addAreaToDB(areaName, anyInt());_  

Not ok:  
_areaService.addAreaToDB(anyString(), anyInt());_  

I don't understand why this happened.